# How to mock Kotlin's Object using Mockito/PowerMockito?

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, kotlin

I have the following class:

```
object CharacterDAO : GenericDAO<Character>(Character::class.java, "id") {
}
```

That I would like to mock using Mockito/PowerMockito. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try this answer to mock kotlin object with mockito:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77242745/14098498

Answer (score 1):

Not using Mockito/PowerMockito, but there's a new library called [Mockk](http://mockk.io) that allows you to do exactly that:

---

From it's documentation:

```
object MockObj {
  fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

objectMockk(MockObj).use {
  assertEquals(3, MockObj.add(1, 2))

  every { MockObj.add(1, 2) } returns 55

  assertEquals(55, MockObj.add(1, 2))
}
```