# How to mock kotlin object for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, powermockito

I have a sample method(which I need to write test case) as given below,

```
 fun setName(val auxName:String) {
        val configUrl = getConfig(auxName)
    }
```

I want to mock the getConfig method and return a specific string value. 
getConfig is a method in a Kotlin Object as below,

```
object Configuration{
    fun getConfig(auxName:String){
    ....
    }
    }
```

Below is the test that I tried

```
@Test
fun setTest()
{
val testname="test"
val testObject=Mockito.mock(Configuration::class.java)
doReturn("configTest").`when`(testObject).getConfig(Mockito.anyString())
setName(testname)
}
```

I am not getting any error but the method getConfig is not mocked. The actual implementation is executed. I tried using Powermockito also. Please help me with this

Comment: How did you know that method is not mocking? Did you tried with verify?

Comment: @0xalihn It was actually entering the mocked method and the original method was getting executed

Answer (score 1):

To mock object class with mockito first you need to put

> `@JvmStatic`
> on the method name

```
object MyObject {

  @JvmStatic
  fun objectFun(context: Context): Boolean {
    // do stuff 
    return true
  }
}

class MyClass(context:Context){

   fun classFun(): Boolean{
     return MyObject.objectFun(context)
   }
}
```

Now to test our class MyClass

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
internal class MyClassTest {

lateinit var mockedContext: Context
lateinit var classUnderTest: MyClass

@Before
fun setUp() {
    mockedContext = mock()
    classUnderTest = MyClass(mockedContext)
}

@Test
fun `your own test`() {
    mockedObject.`when`<Boolean> { MyObject.objectFun(mockedContext) }.thenReturn(true)
    assert(classUnderTest.classFun())
}

/**
 * mock kotlin Object with mockito
 */
companion object {

    lateinit var mockedObject: MockedStatic<MyObject>

    @JvmStatic
    @BeforeClass
    fun init() {
        mockedObject = Mockito.mockStatic(MyObject::class.java)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @AfterClass
    fun close() {
        mockedObject.close()
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably with singleton object, you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978020/3703819

Comment: I tried that but still it is not getting mocked. The original method is getting executed.